# To read the real time data/values in an android application using Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I am stuck in a problem wherein i require to read the real time values in my android application. To be precise, I am able to automate most of the features of my application but stuck at a point.

For a specific activity, that requires to transfer funds from one account to another, i want to read the current balance of the accounts.

Just think it of like this, I have my app's transfer activity, when i click a button it populates  a **list view** with the available accounts with the available balance.

Something like this:

```
                       Account type1            Available Balance


                       Account type2            Available Balance
```

The Account type1 and its available balance is in a linear layout, The Account type2 and its available balance is in a separate linear layout. And these two linear layouts are in a parent linear layout (Got this info from the hierarchyviewer)

My requirement is to read the available balance of the the account types and then carry on with the transfers. How to achieve this using Robotium?

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How to achieve the above mentioned requirement? That is the question.

Comment: In your app is there a way for users to make a transfer? If so then robotium can do probably do it too. For example if the users make a transfer by entering from, to, and amount fields then pressing a submit button, you can write a robotium test that automates those actions.

Comment: @DaveC  i want to read the amount of the values and accordingly choose the 'From' and 'To' accounts to carry forward the transfer. And yes I am able to automate the transfer.

Comment: Please state clearly what the question is.